# What is the difference between removeAllElements() and clear() for DefaultListModel?

Tags: java, swing, defaultlistmodel

What is the difference between `removeAllElements()` and `clear()` method of `DefaultListModel` in java swing?

The [java docs for DefaultListModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) says :-

> public void clear()
>
> Removes all of the
> elements from this list. The list will
> be empty after this call returns
> (unless it throws an exception).

and

> public void removeAllElements()
>
> Removes all components from this list
> and sets its size to zero.

So both basically removes all elements from list so what is the difference? How to decide when to use which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They are both same.**

`DefaultListModel` uses a `Vector` under the hood.
The clear() method was added later when Vector was re-written to fit into the Collection API's.

With version 1.3 the `Collections API` made its' entrance so the `Vector` was re-written to fit into the `List` interface.

In order for it to be backwards compatible, they simply forwarded the calls to the old existing methods where available & possible.

### EDIT

From Java Source:

> ```
> /**
>  * Removes all components from this list and sets its size to zero.
>  * <blockquote>
>  * <b>Note:</b> Although this method is not deprecated, the preferred
>  *    method to use is <code>clear</code>, which implements the 
>  *    <code>List</code> interface defined in the 1.2 Collections framework.
>  * </blockquote>
>  *
>  * @see #clear()
>  * @see Vector#removeAllElements()
>  */
> ```

```
public void removeAllElements() {

        int index1 = delegate.size()-1;
        delegate.removeAllElements();

        if (index1 >= 0) {
            fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, index1);
        }

}
```

Comment: Can we use one of them in place of either any where? or there are some restriction to use?

Comment: If you take a look at `DefaultListModel` source code, you'll see that both methods are **strictly identical**, hence you can use one or the other as you want. I would just add that `clear()` is more meaningful because it is the same method name as for Collections.

Comment: good catch, I hadn't read the javadoc when writing my comment!

Comment: The clear() method wasn't added later according to the Javadoc, otherwise it would have an @since annotation. Conclusion: both methods have been there from the beginning. Collections and Swing were both introduced in 1.2.